# documentDB using collection and document to object

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

I have ObjectModel that contains for example, 2 class Student and Course .

I want to use documentDB for save that 2 collection (one collection for courses and one for students)
I need to create 2 diffrent collection in my documentDB DB ? , Or may I can use only one Collection?

Another problem when I want to convert from document to ObjectModel.Student , I don't want to use dynamic casting (real time performance issue).

```
public static async Task<ObjectModel.Student> GetGroupAsyncByID(string id)
    {
        try
        {
            Document document = await _client.ReadDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(cDatabaseId, cAllCollections[0], id));
            return (ObjectModel.Student)document; // compile error 
        }
        catch (DocumentClientException e)
        {
            if (e.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

My Student Class

```
public class Student 
    {
        #region Fields
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public String StudentName { get; set; }

}
```

How I can cast from Doucment to Student object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

DocumentDB is schema-agonostic and yes, you can save both Course and Student object in one collection. To easily tell which class the Document should be cast to, you can define, for example, "Type" property in both objects and 1 for Course object and 2 for Student object.

The Document object implement the dynamics contract. You can cast to Student by Student s = (dynamics) document. The performance implication here is very minimal because document already contained the PropertyBag of JSON object, it will just set the property of "Student" to the value in PropertyBag.

If you like to handle this yourselves, ResourceResponse also expose the raw stream so that you can handle the deserialization youselves.

Comment: Not sure I'd suggest a `1` and `2` for `Type` unless you're normalizing for some reason (but it seems like a premature optimization to me). Just go with `Course` and `Student`.

Comment: @Ming Liu based on a simple test, dynamic casting is about 20-times slower than static regular C#!!. In addition If I cast every property to my original property type, it's will  be very expensive in meaning of computational time (cast from string to my original type). documentDB not saving the document in binary format (like mongoDB bson). May I missing somthing?